# Converting an alphanumeric string into a numeric one in python

Tags: python, string, alphanumeric

I've got an alphanumeric number as a string "4525ABT2", which I'm trying to "translate" to be only a numeric one. I tried many ways, smart as really stupid and long, and looked all over (I found the solution for Java here but it doesn't work in python. Neither does the solution that change all characters to numbers).
My last attempt looks like this

```
for i in alpha:    
        alpha1 = alpha.replace("A" or "B" or "C", "2")
        alpha2 = alpha1.replace("D" or "E" or "F", "3")
        alpha3 = alpha2.replace("G" or "H" or "I", "4")
        alpha4 = alpha3.replace("J" or "K" or "L", "5")
        alpha5 = alpha4.replace("M" or "N" or "O", "6")
        alpha6 = alpha5.replace("P" or "Q" or "R" or "S", "7")
        alpha7 = alpha6.replace("T" or "U" or "V", "8")
        alpha8 = alpha7.replace("W" or "X" or "Y" or "Z", "9")

phone = str(alpha8)
return phone
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Providing a link to the Java solution that you mention would probably help others a lot to understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: You're right. I should have thought about it. I cannot find the post longer but next time- will do.

Answer (score 5):

Use the proper tool:

```
>>> s = "4525ABT2"
>>> table = str.maketrans('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                          '22233344455566677778889999')
>>> s.translate(table)
'45252282'
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be easier if your replacements were the same size, but this should work:

```
replist = ["","","ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQRS", "TUV", "WXYZ"]

for i,v in enumerate(replist):
    for l in v:
        alpha = alpha.replace(l,str(i))
```

Input: "AHK62ZT"

Output: "2456298"

Comment: this is still a bad solution because replacing characters in a string (in a loop, no less) is expensive.

Comment: @hop oh yeah your solution is much better, I just wanted to provide a version that used the same basic principles as OPs original attempt.